# Prevent newline

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to prevent the blank line in the following output, but setting `parskip` to `0pt` still leaves a blank line:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
My first paragraph\\

My second paragraph
\end{document}
```

The problem is, that I get this output from `pandoc` and the obvious answer not to put a blank line in the `tex` file, doesn't help me.
Therefore, my question I was wondering whether someone has an idea how to prevent the newline.
I am aware, that this is then not really elegant, but I would be very greatful for an good workaround.

Comment: Just remove ``\\``

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph (Latex warns about that)

Comment: You should also read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: If this is the *output*, maybe mind showing the *input*?

Comment: "You should also read an introduction to LaTeX. " `-->` LOL

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. Although I am familiar with some basics of LaTeX, I am not an expert and was not aware that the use of `\\` at the end of a paragraph is actually discouraged.